# Convert timespec to YYYYMMDD in Python

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, python-datetime, python-os

I am using the [.st_birthtime method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) to get the date of creation of a file.

The result looks like:

> 1359492652

which I can convert to a more readable format

> 2013-01-29 21:50:52

using

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(statinfo.st_birthtime)
```

**My question is:** how can I convert it to YYYYMMDD format? I don't give importance of the hours and minutes. In this example the result should be

> 20130129

Something like the `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @date, 112)` of T-SQL.
I am using Python version 3.5.3 and MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this what you wanted?

```
#time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(1359492652))
time.strftime('%Y%m%d', time.gmtime(1359492652))
```

I've assumed that **1359492652** is the total of seconds so this is the right date formatters for Python, tested it in Python 3 interpreter. The first line which is a comment is the same result as you had with the datetime method.

if you want here is a link for the **strftime** behaviour: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior